# How to increment an integer value in Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a little issue with correctly incrementing a value in a Realtime Database.
Here is how it looks:

```
MyList
  + -M93jOoZSx443cxXXDKN
  - -M93jF4qK9MheZvAuX6k
      count: 0
      name: "GHD"
  + -M93jCPkGsW4swOZS0JL
```

Let us say I need to increment count, on the second item from 0 to 1.

This is very simple, nonetheless due to possible concurrent writings it has to be done right. And it is not easy to find out how to do it. I have read that we should use transaction, but haven't found the proper syntax for that. Beside many document do not state clearly if they apply to Realtime Database or not.

[This document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) has an example that I tried to apply but was unsuccessfull.

I tried something like this (wrong):

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('MyList/'+item.ref+'count');
dbRef.transaction(function(currentRank) {
  // If users/ada/rank has never been set, currentRank will be `null`.
  return count + 1;
});
```

To sum it up, my question is what is the correct way to increment my count?

Comment: What is currentRank's value inside the function?

Comment: I do not even reach inside the function. The line "var dbRef = firebase.database().ref....." is already wrong.

Comment: What happens there?

Comment: I get a message telling me the path is wrong. I should not be using item.ref. But the problem is I don't know what to use instead. How am I supposed to refer to the id?

Comment: What is the value of item.ref? Maybe 'MyList/count' would be more helpful. I'm not very knowledgable with Firebase, but I just try to help.

Comment: OK. But there are many items in MyList, each having a count, as you can see looking at my post. How do I set the item?

Comment: In fact I have already caught the item in a snapshot using code like this:
"dbRef.orderByChild('name').equalTo(param).once('value', function(snapshot) {".
I just don't know the proper way to make use of this snapshot.

Comment: I would end the first line with an equalTo and hope that I can reuse it in the next line.